# JPA One to Many Relation How to delete / update child row by ID

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, delete-row

How to delete message by ID? Here's what I do removeMessage(), but I'm not sure is it correct way in JPA? Is there another way? For example create a repository for Message? Or use jdbcTemplate? What would you do?

```
@Entity
class Event {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "event")
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void removeMessage(Long id) {
        messages.removeAll(
            messages.stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getId().equals(id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @Entity(name = "messages")
    static public class Message {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Event event;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Okay, here's how I do it so far

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public void updateMessage(Long messageId, Long eventId, String text) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaUpdate<Event.Message> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Event.Message.class);
    Root m = update.from(Event.Message.class);
    update.set("text", text);
    update.where(
            cb.equal(m.get("id"), messageId),
            cb.equal(m.get("event"), new Event(eventId))
    );
    this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
}

public void deleteMessage(Long messageId, Long eventId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaDelete<Event.Message> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(Event.Message.class);
    Root m = delete.from(Event.Message.class);
    delete.where(
            cb.equal(m.get("id"), messageId),
            cb.equal(m.get("event"), new Event(eventId))
    );
    this.em.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: "The correct way"? There is no single correct way, just an API that allows you to do it. When is removeMessage called and what state is the Event object in at that point? (managed? transient? detached?) because you presumably want those deleted to go back to the datastore at some point ...

Comment: No, it is not correct way to delete. You need to use entity manager for this process.